# Python web с чего начать

Tags: python, веб-программирование

Мне необходимо в кратчайшие сроки написать небольшое серверное приложение на Python. Знаю только основы языка. С чего начать ? Какие фреймворки использовать для backend'а и работы с базой данных ? Из каких источников можно быстро взять информацию ?

Comment: Однозначно http://flask.pocoo.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если в очень короткие сроки, то могу предложить использовать [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) в качестве MVC фреймворка и [peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/) для работы с базой.

Answer (score 0):

А я бы предложил Django. http://djbook.ru/ Вот здесь можно подробно почитать.